# How do I get a "list" of ALL the events in real time in SDL 2.0?

Tags: c++, pygame, sdl, sdl-2

I come from [Pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html), and there I had [pygame.event.get()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get), which returned a list of all events (So, once I had that list of events inside the mainloop, I could check for multiple keypresses or whatever in real-time, since ALL possible events were available).

Now here's my code:

```
#include "init.h"
#include "texture.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Init();

    while (running) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) { // PROBLEM <<< I don't want "POLL".
            auto key = e.key.keysym.sym;
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                running = false;
            } else if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
                if (key == SDLK_ESCAPE) {
                    running = false;
                }
                if (key == SDLK_UP) {
                    square_rect.y -= PLAYER_SPEED;
                } else if (key == SDLK_DOWN) {
                    square_rect.y += PLAYER_SPEED;
                } else if (key == SDLK_LEFT) {
                    square_rect.x -= PLAYER_SPEED;
                } else if (key == SDLK_RIGHT) {
                    square_rect.x += PLAYER_SPEED;
                }
            }

        }

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &square_rect);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

In the tutorials I've seen so far, they've used [SDL_PollEvent()](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryEvents%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29), and I did not notice the difference until now, when I tried to move my square with the keyboard arrows. Obviously, I can't press two arrow keys at once, since the loop is capturing one event at a time.

And the problem is, there's no such thing as "SDL_Event_Get()" in the API. Only these:

- [SDL_PeepEvents()](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PeepEvents?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryEvents%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29)
- [SDL_PollEvent()](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryEvents%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29)
- [SDL_PumpEvents()](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PumpEvents?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryEvents%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29)
- [SDL_PushEvent()](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PushEvent?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryEvents%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29)

Well, I don't know how Pete Shinners ported SDL 1.2 to Python and handled the events in such a marvelous way, so I'm having a hard time understanding SDL 2.0 (I'm probably not the only one). Is there such a thing as "get all the events ()" in SDL 2.0? What if I wanted to check if ALL possible keys were pressed **AT THE SAME TIME**?

Comment: PyGame will not doubt poll underneath - if it blocked for a message you'd have a veryyyyyy slow game loop - edit - for keys he probably just keeps the state of all keys in an array, then you can check this array where/whenever

Comment: When you want to know wheter a key is down or not you can query the `SDL_GetKeyboardState` function.

Comment: "Obviously, I can't press two arrow keys at once, since the loop is capturing one event at a time." This is wrong, you can press multiple keys at once and will get multiple different events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SDL_GetKeyboardState` as described in [the documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetKeyboardState):

```
const Uint8 *state = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
if (state[SDL_SCANCODE_RETURN]) {
    printf("<RETURN> is pressed.\n");
}
if (state[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT] && state[SDL_SCANCODE_UP]) {
    printf("Right and Up Keys Pressed.\n");
}
```

---

Generally speaking you can fetch the events into any container, and then check if any number of events are in such a container. A good container for this would be `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`, but in both cases you would have to define either `operator<` or `std::hash` for the type `SDL_Event`.

An alternative is to make your own generic algorithm that works with any container:

```
template<typename OutIt>
void push_events(OutIt out) {
    SDL_Event e;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
        *out++ = e;
}
```

and then apply it to some container of choice, like `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<SDL_Event> vector;
push_events(std::back_inserter(vector));
```

---

Another option is to keep your own `std::set` of key pressed, in which to "remember" what keys are pressed at any given moment.

For example, given:

```
std::set<SDL_Keycode> keys;
```

then:

```
SDL_Event e;
while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) {
    switch (e.type) {
    case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        auto key = e.key.keysym.sym;
        keys.insert(key);
        break;
    case SDL_KEYUP:
        auto key = e.key.keysym.sym;
        keys.erase(key);
        break;
    }
}
```

and then check via something along the lines of:

```
if (keys.count(SDLK_SPACE) && keys.count(SDLK_UP))
    // ...
```

but I'm not sure what that buys you.